# Azure and authentication: best option for performing additional checks before generating the authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I've used VS 2017 to generate a .NET MVC app that uses Azure AD for authenticate users.

What I'd like to do is perform some additional verifications before injecting the local cookie automatically. In other words, after the user manages to perform his login, I must see if he's been registered as a "local user" by checking an existing table. Is there any hook where this extra verification can be done?

What's the recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, it looks like the best option is to pass a delegate to the SecurityTokenValidated property of the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications during the setup of the openid middleware...